# C# How Can I Transfer Controls From One WinForm To Another And Back?

Tags: c#

I'm writing an app that will play video on the main form or from another form when user clicks Go To Full Screen button. What I want to do is transfer the picture box and playback controls to the Full Screen form. If the user presses the Escape key, the picturebox and playback controls are returned to the main form. The controls show up on the Full Screen form, but the controls don't show up again on the main form after pressing the Escape key.

Here's the code for going to full screen...

```
private void btnGoToFullScreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmFullScreen frm = new frmFullScreen();
    frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    frm.Owner = this;
    pbViewer.Parent = pnlVideoControls.Parent = frm;
    pbViewer.Height = frm.Height;
    pbViewer.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2 - pbViewer.Width / 2, 
                                  Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height / 2 - pbViewer.Height / 2);
    pnlVideoControls.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2 - pnlVideoControls.Width / 2,
                                          Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - 200);
    frm.Show();
}
```

And here's the code to return the controls to the main form...

```
private void frmMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {    
        frmMain.Controls.Add(pbViewer);
        frmMain.Controls.Add(pnlVideoControls);
        pbViewer.Size = Properties.Settings.Default.Portrait;
        pbViewer.Location = new Point(16, 24);
        pnlVideoControls.Location = new Point(145, 418);
        pbViewer.Show(); pbViewer.BringToFront();
        pnlVideoControls.Show(); pnlVideoControls.BringToFront();
        this.Refresh();
        foreach (frmFullScreen frm in this.OwnedForms)
        {
            frm.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: PictureBox is pbViewer and pnlVideoControls is the panel with playback buttons.

Comment: Yes, you can play with Controls.Remove and Controls.Add: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls

Comment: Why would you do that instead of just making 5he form full screen?

Comment: Don't transfer controls, duplicate them and transfer their states. Or better: resize and move a single form when the user toggles between fullscreen and windowed.

Comment: You will likely find that having copies of the controls on both forms (that you hide and reveal as needed) will be a simpler implementation. Yes this breaks the _DRY_ principle (**D**o not **R**epeat **Y**ourself), but your code will be simpler to write, to get working and to maintain. What you will want to do is have a single implementation of the code that each control activates.

Comment: hmm... well, I'm not sure of this approach.. but have you tried `pbViewer.Parent = pnlVideoControls.Parent = frmMain;` to reflect on the differences between the two function scopes:  In one method you're assigning the parent to an existing control. The other attempts to add an existing control (that has a parent) as a child to the main form.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I'm wondering if I could just enlarge the picturebox directly to full screen instead of on a separate form. Any way to do that?